# Unable to find telepot 7.0 in OpenShift

Tags: python, pip, openshift, telegram-bot

I'm using pip 1.4.1 and I'm on python 2.7.
Why am I unable to find telepot 7.0?

```
remote: Stopping Python 2.7 cartridge
remote: Building git ref 'master', commit dae816e
remote: Activating virtenv
remote: Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..
remote: Downloading/unpacking telepot>=7.0 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/5717501c0c1e66f9cd0000e9/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement telepot>=7.0 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/5717501c0c1e66f9cd0000e9/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 2.34, 2.50, 2.51, 2.60, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 4.0, 4.1, 5.0, 6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4)
remote: Cleaning up...
remote: No distributions matching the version for telepot>=7.0 (from -r /var/lib/openshift/5717501c0c1e66f9cd0000e9/app-root/runtime/repo/requirements.txt (line 1))
```

Comment: `pip search 'telepot`' finds "telepot (2.50)  - Python framework for Telegram Bot API" for me, so version 7 or greater won't work.  Is it your requirements.txt that's specifying it?

Comment: I fixed this by ssh ing into it and pip installing there and it found it.